# Increase/specify vscode+clangd parsing timeout

Tags: performance, visual-studio-code, timeout, settings, clangd

I use vscode with clangd extension. Clangd works really nice, but when I am editing the file, clangd starts parsing it almost right away, with minimum timeout. As a result it consumes lots of cpu and shows lots of errors for nothing, before I finish typing. Is it possible to specify some kind of timeout, so that clangd waits a couple of seconds before parsing the file that changed?

I looked into `clangd --help` and `clangd --help-hidden`, but I couldn't find any arguments  that could specify that. I also didn't find anything in vscode settings (I mean there are some timeouts and delays that I can specify, but none of them seems to be the one I'm looking for).

My OS is Ubuntu, but I think it shouldn't matter.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is currently no such option. I believe the timeout is specified in the source code [here](https://searchfox.org/llvm/rev/3cba33c56f6642df1e2f73008749a42b913b13bb/clang-tools-extra/clangd/ClangdServer.h#149). You could consider filing an issue at https://github.com/clangd/clangd/issues/ to request adding a way to configure this value.